# why flash doesn't cover whole of my web page?

Tags: asp.net

I want to show a flash file in my Default.aspx page.
when I use an html file the flash covers whole the page, this is Html source code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>home</title>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#d3d3d3" style="margin:0px;">
<!--url's used in the movie-->
<!--text used in the movie-->
<!-- saved from url=(0013)about:internet -->
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%" id="home" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="movie" value="home.swf" /><param name="menu" value="false" />
    <param name="quality" value="High" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#d3d3d3" /> 
        <embed src="../swf/home.swf" menu="false" quality="High" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#d3d3d3" width="100%" height="100%" name="home" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I put it in my default.aspx file it's height doesn't cove whole the page.
this is my default.aspx source file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="UI_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#d3d3d3" style="margin:0px;">
<!--url's used in the movie-->
<!--text used in the movie-->
<!-- saved from url=(0013)about:internet -->
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%" id="home" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="movie" value="home.swf" /><param name="menu" value="false" />
    <param name="quality" value="High" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#d3d3d3" /> 
        <embed src="../swf/home.swf" menu="false" quality="High" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#d3d3d3" width="100%" height="100%" name="home" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XHTML, the `body` element is not as magical, and doesn't have to be as high as the window.

Set the height of both the `html` and `body` elements to `100%`, and set both the `margin` and `padding` of the `body` element (as some browsers have a default padding instead of margin):

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
</style>
```

Comment: sorry it's right in fire fox, but the flash doesn't work in IE and chrome at all. it doesn't show any thing

Comment: @Raymond Morphy: Check the address to the swf, you are using different URLs for the different embedding methods.

Comment: no my address is right an I have just on 'embed' tag. I had a problem with '<param  name="src" value="../swf/home.swf" />' and I added it to my code and now it's working in IE but not working in chrome. why?

Comment: @Raymond Morphy: No, you have one URL in the `embed` tag, and another URL in the `movie` parameter in the `object` tag. Both are needed, as different browsers support only one or the other.